# dictionary error Exception has occurred: NameError free variable referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python, dictionary, runtime-error

I am getting following error for assigning dictionary
`Data = {}`   was declared at the top of the python file. 
When I was assigning the Data dictionary with values in another python function, I got this error

```
Data[key] = {'name1':dataArr[1],'name2':dataArr[2],'name3':dataArr[3],'name4':dataArr[4],'name5':dataArr[5]}
```

> Exception has occurred: NameError free variable 'Data'
>   referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Answer (score 1):

Although the dictionary was declared at the top of the program. The assignment of dictionary was erroring out when I called for assignment within a submethod. 
Python in that sense is slightly different than C#.

```
#global scope
Data = {}

#Assign method
Data[key] = {'name1':dataArr[1],'name2':dataArr[2],'name3':dataArr[3],'name4':dataArr[4],'name5':dataArr[5]}


# main method
#this is duplication of assignment, but this resolved the issue. Would love to know why this was needed.
Data = {}
# Assign method
```

Not sure, why I had to duplicate the assignment for Data = {} , but this solution works. Would love to know why Python needs this assignment second time, when I already assigned it at global scope.